# Alternative to ' or "?

Tags: php, variables, fwrite

I am using PHP fwrite to enter HTML and PHP into a file
The problem is this, I have used ' ' to enclose what $content is ie. the HTML and PHP,

Then I used " " to enclose

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE.....
```

which is in $content,

but now i am stuck when i want to do this:

```
  WHERE var1="$var1" and var2="$var2"
```

because I've already used ' ' and " " and if i used one of these it obiviously wouldn't work

Any ideas for an alternative way to get around this problem?? is there any other symbols similar to ' or "?

Thanks in advance
Niall

Comment: Just escape your quotes inside the string: `\"` or `\'`

Comment: **What for you need PHP code writing PHP code into a file?** That's very unusual and quite dangerous practice. Are you certainly sure you need that?

Comment: You are not supposed to use `"` for SQL strings anyway. This will fail in `mysql --ansi` compliant mode.

Comment: maybe he's working on a developer forum that has code in the question ….

Comment: As another alternative, I would go with `mysqli` or `pdo` and use prepared statements. Then you do not have to worry about quotes etc. If I get time I may add an answer with how to go about it.

Comment: I'm creating a personal page for each user as they register... they pick a username (say Texteri.com/StackOverflow) my site allows you send free texts, you see there is a phonebook and the php is used to retrieve contacts, display them and then allows you select to text them.. get me??

Comment: This is most likely the wrong way to do this. The solution is to have **one** dynamic page that accepts an `id` parameter of some sort and executes the queries accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tbl_name . ' WHERE var1="' . $var1 . '"';
```

That being said, unless `$var1` is an integer or otherwise sanitized, your code will be vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).

Comment: yeah i haven't even gone near injection yet its just started i'll tell you in a sec if it works :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

You can escape the " or ' character by putting backslashes in front of it:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE var1=\"$var1\" and var2=\"$var2\""`

*Please make sure you call addslashes (or anything similar) on $var1 and $var2 before executing this query, if you do not want to be vulnerable to SQL Injection*.

Answer (score 2):

you could do this:

```
 $sql='select * from '.$tblname.' where...
```

Comment: ..but certainly shouldn't. Use sprintf() for such things.

Comment: How true. As I remember my teachers saying 'always read the question'.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any alternatives.

## Just do not write PHP code into a file with your code.

Look, you are using PHP awfully wrong way.

Instead of **writing another PHP page for the every new user** you have to use only one PHP page to serve them all.

This page would operate some **data storage**, a database or a text file, and display it to the user.

That's the way every PHP application works: single PHP code, multiple data.

Comment: Seconded. Generating code is the wrong way to do it in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape your quotes with a backslash.  So in your $sql variable you can use

```
\" Escaped Double Quote.
\' Escaped Single Quote.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use single quote inside of SQL queries as well:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE var1='some string value' AND var2='$var2'";
```

Or just use string concatenation, which works for both single and double enquoted strings:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE var1='" . $var1 . "' AND var2='" . $var2 . "'";
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tbl_name . ' WHERE var1="'. $var1 . '" AND var2="' . $var2 . '"';
```

Answer (score 1):

While all the answers above are correct I want to point out a more elegant solution:

```
sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE var1 = "%s" AND var2 = %d', "tableName, "someString", 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already enclosed the string in "", you do not need to add them again around $var1 and $var2

Answer (score 0):

Use the heredoc syntax as described in the PHP manual.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: -1 as the heredoc syntax for something like this is way overkill, in my opinion.

Comment: Seriously? You're gonna mark me down for offering a perfectly valid (if overkill) solution? It may not be the best but it's not disinformation or wrong. Seriously?!

Comment: It may not be disinformation, but to me it is considered bad practice. So in my opinion, this is bad advice, and hence the downvote to put it below the more "accepted" / "better" advice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any alternate to ' or ".
You can escape ' or " by placing \ before it

for example

```
$sql = "SELECT * from $table_name where var1=\"$var1\" and var2=\"$var2\""
```

after execution, string inside $sql will be

```
SELECT * from my_table where var1="var1_value" and var2="var2_value"
```